# Algorithm for Multi-Class Classification of News Article

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm, random-forest, document-classification

I want to classify the news article into the category it belongs to. I have 4 categories of news eg." Technology,Sports,Politics and Health." And i have collected around 50 documents for each category as a Training Set

**Is the Training data enough for classification ??? And Which Algorithm should i use for classification?? SVM, Random Forest,Knn, ??

I am using Scikit-learn http://scikit-learn.org/ [python] library for my task

Thanks

Comment: Data is enough to train, but I doubt your accuracy will be high on new data.

Comment: It's good if you use Naive-Bayes since it works on small training set too. But I suggest you to use more training data since accuracy increases when the size of training data increases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to attack this problem form CRFs to Random Forests.

With your limited training data, I would suggest going with a model with high bias such as the linear SVM.  Start with training one vs all models for each class and predicting the class with the highest probably.  This will give you a baseline for how hard your problem is with the given training data.

Comment: train on 90% of your data and see what the error is on the 10% not used for training.  That will give you an estimate of how hard the problem is. The answer to how much training data you need is always "more".  Also, remember that 99% accuracy is easily achievable if 99% of the examples are all from the same class.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer you to use Naive-Bayes classification. There is a tool called Ling-pipe where this is already implemented. What you want to do is just refer

http://alias-i.com/lingpipe/demos/tutorial/classify/read-me.html

There you have a small sample program Classifynews.java. Run that program by training the data and apply testing .A training data sample is given as "20 newsgroups"

http://qwone.com/~jason/20Newsgroups/

Training can be applied by training the data and if needed you can build an intermediate model and then apply the test data into that model. Naive-Bayes is good for the cases where training data is small.

But its accuracy increases as the size of training data increases. So try to include more news groups. Good luck. Try this and let me know